# strptime and as.Date producing NAs instead of a proper date.

Tags: r

Quick sanity check.

Why isn't either of these working, and I'm getting NA values? It was working earlier.

```
> as.Date("1-Jan-18",format = "%m-%b-%y")
[1] NA
> strptime("1-Jan-18",format = "%m-%b-%y")
[1] NA
```

It all went wrong after I tried passing the TZ value, but that could be unrelated.

Comment: You need `%d` (day) instead of `%m` (month).  here `%b` is for the month name.  The full list of format abbreviations with description can be found in `?strptime`

Comment: Thanks, I was having a mental block